Vector to raster error (rasterize)
I have the problem, that there is always the same error when trying to use the tool rasterize (see below). I tried it in different Qgis projects and with several layers and I couldn't find any helpful ideas yet. Maybe someone knows a solution?

ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL
varid .  at
(D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.8.2\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,6738)
ERROR 1: netcdf error #-50 : NetCDF: Action prohibited on NC_GLOBAL
varid .  at
(D:\src\osgeo4w\src\gdal\gdal-3.8.2\frmts\netcdf\netcdfdataset.cpp,netCDFDataset::AddProjectionVars,6743)


I have exactly the same issue.
No idea how to resolve it. I use CRS EPSG:2056. On my windows pc there is no problem, only with the linux version of QGIS.
